# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function content_try()

Tags: php, drupal, phpunit

I am new to phpunit. I want to use it with drupal( drupal.org)
my test file in a folder called functional_test which is in the root directory
of the site. If you wish to see the full directory structure then
see it here http://pastebin.com/TaqGLq8u

However when I run it I get the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function content_try() in /home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/drupal_test/functional_test/index_Test.php on line 23

I am sure index.php is getting found as the you can see the full output
here http://pastebin.com/FVkn2ig1

Also if I put the test file outside the functional directory in the root directory it works

My test code is very simple:

```
require_once '../index.php';


class index_Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
 public function test_content_try()
{
    $value=content_try();
    $this->assertEquals('1', $value,'Value should be one');

}
}
```

My index.php file which I want to test is:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();


function content_try()
{

return 1;
}
```

I am not clear what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't know anything about php, but my guess would be a missing "public" for content_try

Comment: Learn about variable scopes.
Move `require_once '../index.php';` into test method

Comment: @npst public did not do it.

Comment: @kryoz  even after putting it inside the test method it did not work. As I mentioned above if I move the file to the root directory it works as long as I change require_once from '../index.php' to 'index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally the answer was in two parts

1) http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/organizing-tests.html

Here I learnt that phpunit will follow the directory structure and one should place their tests based on that.I made on drupal dir and one test dir and followed their instructions

2) In addition I needed to chdir('folder_of_drupal') for the errors to go.
http://pastebin.com/hcgt1zmQ